# Xamarin.iOS bind Objective C block to the C# code

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I'm working on a Xamarin.iOS binding for the following Objective C code

```
@interface Logger : NSObject

+ (void)setLogBlock:(void (^)(NSString* message, void* argument))logBlock;

@end
```

So far I have following code:

```
// @interface Logger : NSObject
[BaseType(typeof(NSObject))]
public partial interface Logger
{
    // +(void)setLogBlock:(void (^)(NSString *, void *))logBlock;
    [Static]
    [Export("setLogBlock:")]
    void SetLogBlock(LogDelegate logBlock);
}

// This declares the callback signature for the block:
public delegate void LogDelegate(NSString message, IntPtr arg);
```

This compiles fine but the app crashes when I start using it with following crash on iOS Simulator:

```
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.047 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical: 
    Native stacktrace:

    2016-06-24 16:47:01.055 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    0   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x09cf2f4d mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 317
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.055 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x09c419f6 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 214
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.055 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x0c3ef79b _sigtramp + 43
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.055 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    3   ???                                 0xffffffff 0x0 + 4294967295
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.055 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    4   libdispatch.dylib                   0x0c099456 dispatch_async + 342
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    5   BindingTest                         0x00069ba3 otk_objc_log + 276
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    6   BindingTest                         0x00537207 otk_console_append + 295
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    7   BindingTest                         0x005385bb otk_ev_timer_callback + 155
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    8   BindingTest                         0x0050ef4f uv__run_timers + 159
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    9   BindingTest                         0x004fcba8 uv_run + 120
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    10  BindingTest                         0x00538f74 otk_ev_thread_main + 148
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.056 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    11  BindingTest                         0x00065f78 otkit_session_start_thread + 21
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.057 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0c3dc780 _pthread_body + 138
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.057 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    13  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0c3dc6f6 _pthread_body + 0
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.057 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical:    14  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0c3d9f7a thread_start + 34
    2016-06-24 16:47:01.057 BindingTest[26019:1633387] critical: 
    =================================================================
    Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
    a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
    used by your application.
    =================================================================
```

iOS device crashes with following stack trace:

```
    Jun 24 19:11:26 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: ------------------------------------------------
    Jun 24 19:11:29 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical: Stacktrace:
    Jun 24 19:11:29 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at <unknown> <0xffffffff>
    Jun 24 19:11:29 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at (wrapper managed-to-native) System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.CheckCurrentDomain (int) <0x00007>
    Jun 24 19:11:29 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.op_Explicit (intptr) [0x0001b] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.InteropServices/GCHandle.cs:124
    Jun 24 19:11:29 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at System.Runtime.InteropServices.GCHandle.FromIntPtr (intptr) [0x00000] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/_build/Library/Frameworks/Xamarin.iOS.framework/Versions/git/src/mono/mcs/class/corlib/System.Runtime.InteropServices/GCHandle.cs:166
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at ObjCRuntime.BlockLiteral.get_Target () [0x00015] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/3339/39ebb778/source/maccore/src/ObjCRuntime/Blocks.cs:126
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at ObjCRuntime.Trampolines/SDOpenTokLogBlockDelegate.Invoke (intptr,intptr,intptr) [0x00009] in ....iOS/obj/Debug/ios/ObjCRuntime/Trampolines.g.cs:60
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   at (wrapper native-to-managed) ObjCRuntime.Trampolines/SDOpenTokLogBlockDelegate.Invoke (intptr,intptr,intptr) <0x000a7>
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical: 
        Native stacktrace:
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   0   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x00000001008fe438 mono_handle_native_sigsegv + 260
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   1   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000100909074 mono_sigsegv_signal_handler + 336
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   2   libsystem_platform.dylib            0x00000001830d994c _sigtramp + 68
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   3   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x0000000100991334 mono_gchandle_is_in_domain + 20
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   4   libmonosgen-2.0.dylib               0x000000010093e174 mono_gc_GCHandle_CheckCurrentDomain + 32
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   5   libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x0000000100ef1ec0 wrapper_managed_to_native_System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandle_CheckCurrentDomain_int + 96
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   6   libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x0000000100ef1de8 System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandle_op_Explicit_intptr + 56
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   7   libmscorlib.dll.dylib               0x0000000100ef22fc System_Runtime_InteropServices_GCHandle_FromIntPtr_intptr + 28
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   8   libXamarin.iOS.dll.dylib            0x0000000100c92b8c ObjCRuntime_BlockLiteral_get_Target + 76
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   9   libOpenTok.iOS.dll.dylib    0x00000001020a05bc ObjCRuntime_Trampolines_SDOpenTokLogBlockDelegate_Invoke_intptr_intptr_intptr + 236
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   10  libOpenTok.iOS.dll.dylib    0x00000001020b07f8 wrapper_native_to_managed_ObjCRuntime_Trampolines_SDOpenTokLogBlockDelegate_Invoke_intptr_intptr_intptr + 168
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   11  libOpenTok.iOS.dll.dylib    0x0000000101b38428 __otk_objc_log_block_invoke6 + 48
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ec54bc <redacted> + 24
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ec547c <redacted> + 16
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ed14c0 <redacted> + 864
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ec8f80 <redacted> + 464
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   16  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ed3390 <redacted> + 728
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   17  libdispatch.dylib                   0x0000000182ed30b0 <redacted> + 112
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   18  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001830dd470 _pthread_wqthread + 1092
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical:   19  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001830dd020 start_wqthread + 4
    Jun 24 19:11:30 am-6s Test[4795] <Warning>: critical: 
        =================================================================
        Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
        a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
        used by your application.
        =================================================================
```

Please advise.

Comment: where do you execute it? Is your used library in the binding a fat static library (contains all CPU architectures that you want to support)?

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe iOS simulator, compiling for devices produces following error:
MTOUCH: error MT3001: Could not AOT the assembly `iOSBinding.dll`

Comment: Have you linked the x86 / x64 version of the library to the binding?

Comment: Yes, all archs are there.

Comment: @Sven-MichaelStübe MT3001 was complaining about missing framework nobody specified in the binding library dependencies :) Checking on the device

Comment: Device is crashing also

Comment: Is this for the OpenTok library?

Comment: Please add to your post your current binding project and sample. It would also be beneficial to include your `LinkWith.cs`, `ApiDefinition.cs`, and `StructsAndEnums.cs` in the post. (Or just upload the binding project)